# Facebook Share link NOT IN correct language

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a FB app that has a share button.
The app was created by someone who had their fb account in Italian.

Now we're testing everything and found out that when hitting the share button, the share information, such as "Post on Your Wall" is in Italian. He has changed his fb page to English and we've changed the app language settings to be in English as well.
Even when I test it from my computer, same results.

Could this be an actual bug in Facebook?
Any help please?

Thanks,

**JB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to specify the locale when you add the fb snippet to your page.

Read more there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization#plugins